# Draggable inside resizable - the drag item is not shown

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

I have been trying to get a fundamental drag and drop interface to work. I have it working using a set of divs, but when I alter the divs to be a resizable accordion, I find that the image will not be displayed when I move outside the bounds of the resizable div. The cursor remains and the image of the dragged items appears to be drawn on the resizable div. You can see the scroll bars move when the cursor moves off the accordion.
The drop operation "appears" to be picked up as expected. The only issue is the retaining the visibility of the dragged item. I have tried `zIndex` with no effect.

I would have included the image and example code that shows the effect, but I don't have 10 reputation to post images.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="./jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mainDemo.css">
    <style>
    #accordion-resizer {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            heightStyle: "fill"
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
            minHeight: 140,
            minWidth: 50,
            resize: function() {
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(init);
        function init() {
             $('#cardPile').html('');
            var numbers = [ 'test a ','test b', 'test c' ];
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                createItem(numbers[i], '#baseWidgets', ['#content','#selection'], '#baseWidgets div' );
            }
             $('#displayCanvas').droppable({
             accept: '#baseWidgets div',
             hoverClass: 'hovered',
             drop:handleCardDrop
             });
        }
        function createItem( title, parent, container, stack )
        {
            var el = '<div>' + title + '</div>';
            var $div = $(el).data('number', title).attr('id', 'card' + title).appendTo(parent).draggable({
              containment: ['displayCanvas','content'],
                stack: stack,
                cursor: 'move',
                zIndex:1000,
                scroll: false,
                revert: true
            });
          }
        function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="accordion-resizer" >
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>Basic</h3>

                <div id ="selection" >
                    <div id="baseWidgets"> </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Advanced</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Some data</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="displayCanvas">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Arial", "Helvetica", "Verdana", "sans-serif";
}

table {
    font-size: 1em;
}

#selection {
    margin: 2px 2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.imgcls {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #a8cad0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.demo-description {
    clear: both;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}


#baseWidgets div.ui-draggable-dragging {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
#displayCanvas
{
    margin: 2px 2px;
    height: 92%;
    width: 99.5%;
    top: 4%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background: #ebedf2;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 8px;
}


#content {
    margin: 2px 2px;
    height: 92%;
    width: 99.5%;
    top: 4%;
    position: fixed;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background: #ebedf2;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 8px;

}
```

Comment: You've pasted way too much code for it to be easily reviewed. Secondly, can you please recreate the issue you're seeing over at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)? This will help easily visualize the side-effect you're seeing.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart  is this what you're trying to do?